# How to properly get user response from Google Actions json response

Tags: actions-on-google

I've been working with Google Actions **API.ai** and I have an app based on number genie.  The user triggers an intent and responds with the number and I have to use that number in my nodejs app running at the webhook.

So should I parse the `json` where I can see **result.action.check_guess:65**.

**Or** follow the sample code which uses:

```
let guess = parseInt(assistant.getArgument('check_guess'));
```

What is recommended and what are the pros and cons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters - both are perfectly valid and well documented (documentation for [AssistantApp](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejs/AssistantApp) and for the [JSON](https://developers.google.com/actions/apiai/webhook#response)). The actions-on-google module is great if you're using node.js, but using the JSON directly is also perfectly workable if you're familiar with working with JSON.

In particular, it is best to use the actions-on-google package if:

- You're using node.js
- You may be switching away from API.AI at some point (since the actions-on-google package for API.AI and native work very similarly).
- You don't want to get into some of the implementation details (the package abstracts many of the parameters and contexts into the simpler "data" field).

However, using JSON and the API directly is best (or essential) if:

- You aren't using node.js
- You are making more complex use of API.AI's contexts or other features
- You may want to support your bot for more than the Google Assistant (ie - for some of the other bot platform integrations that API.AI supports).

Comment: Could you please clear up for me: the actions-on-google module is what gives me access to the object ApiAssistant, right?  I've run into a snag where the post gets made even from the welcome intent, before the ApiAssistant check is made.

Comment: Yes. The actions-on-google module provides the ApiAiAssistant object. If you have another question, your best bet is to post about it with as much details as you can rather than try to use a previously answered question.